# Removing groups and users from Azure DevOps Git repository permissions without Inheritance

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

Up until quite recently, it was possible to fine-tune the security settings of individual groups and users  in a given Azure DevOps Git repository by disabling inheritance, then unsetting their permissions. With the recent change of UI, this appears to no longer be possible: If I

1. untoggle Inheritance for a given repository,
2. click the trash can icon next to the group I want to remove (screenshot below),

I get the error message

> {group or user} has inherited permissions and cannot be removed from the list

even though Inheritance is explicitly disabled on the repository (as well as all of its tags and branches).

[image]

Again, this worked fine until recently, and I have examples of repositories where the otherwise inherited groups and users have been removed. If I take such a repository (screenshot below, note that all groups are removed), enable Inheritance and disable it immediately afterwards, then all the groups and users will also contaminate this repository and appear to be unremovable.

One other odd piece of behavior I noticed: While clicking the trash can next to "Project Collection Administrators" did not remove the group, it did have the side effect of setting all permissions for the *different* group "Project Collection Service Accounts" to "Not set".

[image]

So my question is: Is this a regression in Azure DevOps Repos, or is there a new way to fine-tune permissions on a repository that I'm missing?

Comment: .Do you get the error in every group?

Comment: Every group except "Project Collection Build Service Account", actually. That one can be removed, even though it's also displayed at the general "Git repositories" level.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, even disable the Inheritance, there will still has residue.

*Note: This does not occurred on all repositories. Just some of them has.*

> {group or user} has inherited permissions and cannot be removed from
>   the list

When you saw this error message, focus on right panel and confirm is there any `System` words display in it. Like this:

[image]

This is what I said the **residue**.

Modify it as `Allow`(or any other you want), just make it without `system`.

Click on the trash can icon, and you will see it can be deleted.

Comment: There are no entries containing "(system)" in my case.

Comment: @fuglede, Do the action and then check F12, and see the response body of `Post  https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery`. Just check  `isPermissionGrantedBySystem` and `confirm` whether there has true value with this. These 2 days, we are deploying M164 to all accounts. Not sure is this affected? But until now, all of my side are work fine.

Comment: In `ms.vss-admin-web.security-view-members-data-provider.subjectPermissions`, you mean?  If so, none of the returned objects have `isPermissionGrantedBySystem` as a key. Only `displayName`, `namespaceId`, `token`, `bit`, `canEdit`, and `permissionDisplayString` appear.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite funny...
So, I disabled inheritance and started to remove roles one by one, and nothing got deleted, because of the same issue.
However, after I refreshed page, I couldn't access to the pipeline because it actually deleted all roles I chose and there was my role as well :D

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me: toggle the inheritance switch off - on - off, then:
if stops working again, toggle it on and off again each and every time before clicking the trash button.
I tend to believe that the reason for your trouble (and mine) are periodical jobs ran by the organization which maintain a certain state in the permissions' section